# A função updateOne não está funcionando, me retorna OK, mas não altera nada

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Estou utilizando MongoDB para fazer a persistência de dados na minha aplicação, com NodeJS.

Faço a chamada assim:

```
module.exports = function (app) {
    var dbConfig = app.config.db;

    return {
        changeAccountStatus: function (request, response, next, obj) {
            dbConfig.mongoclient.connect(dbConfig.mongourl, function(err, db) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    db.close();
                }
                else{
                    var dbo = db.db(dbConfig.mongodbname);
                    dbo.collection("driver").updateOne({_id: obj._id}, {$set: {accountstatus: obj.accountstatus}}, function(err, result) {
                        //Código do handler
                    });
                    db.close();
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Envio um JSON via POST:

```
{
    "_id":"5a7234ee869cd6058834acae",
    "accountstatus":"active"
}
```

O campo `$filter` do `updateOne` ficaria: `{ _id: '5a7234ee869cd6058834acae' }`

E o `$update`: `{ '$set': { accountstatus: 'active' } }`

Ao meu ver, o código está tudo certo; envio um ID existente juntamente com o novo `accountStatus` que desejo alterar. Mas sempre recebo a mensagem.

```
{ n: 0, nModified: 0, ok: 1 }
```

Que nada foi modificado. Não sei o que estou fazendo errado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ele pode não estar encontrando o documento devido a busca pelo `_id` ser ObjectID, então você pode fazer o seguinte:

```
const {ObjectId} = require('mongodb');
[...]
updateOne({_id: new ObjectId(obj._id)}
```

Comment: Imaginei que pudesse ser algo assim, em outros lugares que li sobre dizia que podia utilizar somente a string, mas vou testar de qualquer forma, já que não estou chegando a lugar nenhum.

Comment: ok, quando concluir volta aqui pra dizer se deu certo =]

Comment: De fato funcionou, porém só um adendo na sua resposta, o função `ObjectId()` não necessita do `new`, da pra utilizar diretamente após dar `var mongodb = require('mongodb')` deste modo: `mongodb.ObjectId(obj._id)`